# Shift the rendered output in 2d space

Tags: javascript, three.js

Consider [this simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/meetamit/ya2hnqpq/1/) of a cube centered on the origin of the world. Since the camera is looking directly at it, the resulting rendered image shows the cube in the middle of the rendered 2D image and only its front face is visible. I'd like to have control over that cube's placement. I.e. I'd like to shift the rendered output up and to the left by some amount. That way, I can for example shift everything by half of the canvas's width and height and have the cube centered on the top left corner of the rendered output.

To be clear: I don't want to move the camera nor the object in the 3D world (nor the canvas). I just want the rendered result itself to shift, and I'd like to **define this shift in 2D screen units** rather than in 3D space. It entails that after the said shift, the sides of the cube will still **not be visible** — only the front face as it is currently. It also entails that if I shift the output to the left, some geometry that's on the right side of the view but previously out of the frame would now shift into view and get rendered.

In some 3D software I've encountered the ability to do this by modifying the camera's X and Y "center shift". Maybe in three.js I'd have to do it by applying a transformation to the camera or to the renderer? I'm not familiar enough with the library to know where to dig.

```
There's no relevant code to share, but StackOverflow won't let me submit this question without some code ;)
```

Comment: Do you expect all objects to be rendered in this way or is the cube special? ie: if another object was shifted into view by moving the cube and camera to the upper left then would the new object be drawn from the new perspective of the camera in the upper left or does it have to be "straight on" as well?

Comment: @fmacdee I see what you mean; thanks for asking.... No, I'm not looking for everything to be "straight on". If there were another cube off to the right, we'd be able to see its left face before and after the shift. It'd be as if the canvas were moved, but without moving the canvas, just the center. Sort of like changing the cropping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You offset of the camera using a pattern like so:

```
var fullWidth = window.innerWidth;
var fullHeight = window.innerHeight;
var xPixels = 600;
var yPixels = 200;

camera.setViewOffset ( fullWidth, fullHeight, xPixels, yPixels, fullWidth, fullHeight );
```

To undo it, call

```
camera.clearViewOffset();
```

See the [docs](http://threejs.org/docs/api/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.html) for more info about this method and multi-monitor setups. It works for `OrthographicCamera`, too.

three.js r.84

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use canvas `translate`?

Just do something like this:

```
  // adjust for camera
  ctx.translate(-this.camera.x, -this.camera.y);

  // render scene here

  // end of camera view
  ctx.translate(this.camera.x, this.camera.y);
```

Comment: Thanks @Mykybo, but 1) I couldn't get it to work (if I obtain `ctx` using `getContext('webgl')` I get an error that `translate` is not a method, and if I `getContext('2d')` it returns null), and more importantly 2) WestLangley's answer uses a three.js method of the camera — not the canvas — which seems most appropriate for this.